# Can I use a Shrinkwrap Modifier for this shape?

Tags: modeling

This is the extention of the question posted previously 'How can I join these two meshes together?'. I'm trying to tranform the face surrounded by a red border into a honey comb face. So I am wondering if applying a Shrinkwrap is possible because I tried in vain (I can't select the face as the target). I could move the honey comb manually but it's defininitely tedious and unperfect. Thanks[image]

Comment: 1. The Shrinkwrap modifier uses two separate objects. your meshes seem to be submeshes of one object. 2. Since it only works with meshes, you won't be able to choose a single face of one object as the target.

Comment: So what is the best way to replace the smooth face of the mesh with a honey comb face?

Comment: Consider using a texture. If this mesh shape won't be a part of physics simulation, there is no need  to add geometry, when texture will fix the look.

Comment: A possible workflow: Duplicate the faces you want to have as target. Separate them as a new object (select and press "P"), then use that object as target for the shrinkwrap. when you are happy with the result apply the modifier. Then you can get rid of the duplicated opbject.

Comment: I didn't understand quite well what you want to create :/

Comment: I am trying to make a grille honeycomb like the air vents you can see on the sport cars bumpers.